# import products database wordpress woocommerce

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce, insert, product

**First I am really sorry for probably the stupid question,
but I do not know where else to search for the answer.
So my question is :
I have a wordpress website , woocommerce installed and a supplier who sent
me this database and a code to download all of his info and structure.
This is part of the link thay send me

> .................. 54678|5132329|Конструктори и
>   Пъзели|Фигури|19.00|0.480|Bakugan|M|://rayatoys.com/pic/G815132329-34.90.JPG|Бакуган кутия за бакугани|Бакурак кутия за бакугани Предлага се от Раяленд
>   999-46|506109340|Кукли и аксесоари|Детски музикални
>   инструменти|29.00|0.640|Others -
>   Други|MF|://rayatoys.com/pic/1671354102778112812.jpg|Бебешка
>   китара|Електрическа китара с много забавления за детето. Избор между 3
>   различни музикални стила (рок, поп и блус). 3 типа мелодии (кратки
>   мелодии, записани мелодии и тонове за подражание). Всяка една от 23-те
>   мелодии може да се комбинират с 3 различни функции за миксиране:
>   барабани, вибрация и забързване на ритъма. Работи с батерии 1.5V AA,
>   които не са включени в комплекта. Размери на играчката: 38 / 18 см
>   Размери на кутията: 48 / 25 см Тегло: 0.640кг Подходяща за деца над 1
>   година. Вносител Раяленд EC33|109824|Занимателни|Занимателни
>   игри|9.90|0.560|Others -
>   Други|MF|://rayatoys.com/pic/G235DSC09048.JPG|Магнитен пъзел|Това е
>   една уникална и забавна игра,за развитието на чуждоезиковите
>   способности на вашето дете L44552|109815|Конструктори и
>   Пъзели|Пъзели|6.90|0.630|Others -
>   Други|MF|://rayatoys.com/pic/G240DSC09049.JPG|Пъзел-игра с конци|
>   74023|109804|Конструктори и Пъзели|Пъзели|4.50|0.230|Others -
>   Други|MF|://rayatoys.com/pic/raya147824447220161104.jpg|Пъзел
>   POKEMON|Пъзел с едри елементи. Размери на кутията:15/15/7 Вносител
>   Раяленд 924|108297|Игри|Бебешки играчки|3.50|0.500|Others -
>   Други|MF|://rayatoys.com/pic/G274108297.JPG|Пиано на батерии|Детско
>   пиано на батерии Нужни са 2бр. батерии тип АА, които не са включени
>   Размери на пианото В/Д/Ш- 11/22/2.5см 107173|107173|Кукли и
>   аксесоари|Детски музикални инструменти|24.90|0.890|Others -
>   Други|MF|://rayatoys.com/pic/G285107173.JPG|Ксилофон жабче|Ксилофон
>   жабче В комплекта има шест музикални карти. Чрез тях децата могат да
>   свирят някои от техните любими песнички. Размер: 39 / 22 см. Подходящо
>   за деца над 18 месеца. Вносител Раяленд EQ0551|108674|Конструктори и
>   Пъзели|Пъзели|8.50|0.715|Raya
>   Toys|MF|://rayatoys.com/pic/raya149699818720170609.jpg|Пъзел Операта в
>   Сидни|Пъзел Операта в Сидни Пъзел с 35 едри елемента. Размери на
>   кутията:31/26/6см Размери на пъзела:76см/43см Препоръчителна възраст
>   3+ Вносител Раяленд 16|109512|Кукли и аксесоари|Детски кухни и
>   обзавеждане|3.90|0.100|Others -
>   Други|F|://rayatoys.com/pic/G327109912-3.90.JPG|Диадема за
>   дете|Диадема за дете Пластмасова. Подходяща за деца над 3 години.
>   Вносител Раяленд 6046001|109685|Игри|Бебешки играчки|21.90|0.300|Tiny
>   Love|MF|://rayatoys.com/pic/3591351167733102512.jpg|Плюшен жираф за
>   количка|Плюшен жираф за количка или столче. Подходящ за деца на
>   възраст над 6 месеца. Спомага за развитие на чувството на допир, за
>   развитие на слуха, привличане на вниманието. Размер: В/Ш - 23/15см.
>   389|109085|Кукли и аксесоари|Детски кукли и бебета|6.90|0.295|Others -
>   Други|MF|://rayatoys.com/pic/G378109085-16.00.JPG|Кукла от филма
>   Училищен Мюзикъл|Кукла от филма Училищен Мюзикъл При нас са вече
>   забавните и обичани от децата кукли Училищен мюзикъл,на които могат да
>   се сгъват краката и мърдат ръцете. Размер на кутията: 32/13/6см.
>   Подходяща за деца над 3 години. Тегло: 0.295 кг. Цената е за 1 брой.
>   Доставка според наличността. Вносител Раяленд
>   GA22306|109365|Занимателни|Радиоуправляеми играчки|17.00|0.480|Raya
>   Toys|MF|://rayatoys.com/pic/raya149664920920170605.jpg|Кола LEOPARD с
>   дистанционно управление|Кола LEOPARD с дистанционно управление
>   Управлява се лесно с дистанционното. Върви напред и назад, а предните
>   фарове светят. Може да се движи с до 8 км/ч. Дистанционното е с обхват
>   от около 30 м. Върху горната задна част има добавени два декоративни
>   велосипеда, сякаш ще ходите на екскурзия с тях. В долната част на
>   колата има острилка за моливи - пъхате молив - задейства се
>   автоматична острилка, която остри и задвижва задните гуми. Размери на
>   кутията: в17 х д21 х ш12 см 1 x 9V батерия в дистанционното и 3 х 1.5V
>   АА в колата(не са включени в комплекта) Препоръчителна възраст 3 - 7г.
>   Вносител Раяленд 77591|108883|Конструктори и
>   Пъзели|Фигури|2.60|0.230|Others -
>   Други|M|://rayatoys.com/pic/G645108883-10.50.jpg|Фигури
>   Наруто|Комплекта съдържа 3 фигури с поставки и 2 медальона.
>   108885|108885|Конструктори и Пъзели|Фигури|2.90|0.155|Others -
>   Други|M|://rayatoys.com/pic/G647108885_6.50.JPG|Фигури
>   Наруто|Комплекта съдържа 1 фигура,ръкавици и ластик за китка.
>   010|109241|Конструктори и Пъзели|Моделини и
>   пластилини|1.10|0.030|Others -
>   Други|MF|://rayatoys.com/pic/G706109241_2.20.JPG|Дунапренена
>   пръчка|Пръчката има светлини ефекти. Необходими батерии тип АG13 3
>   броя 108380|108380|Спортни|Тротинетки ролери
>   скейбордове|2.50|0.090|Others ..........

And this is a code:

```
if (($handle = fopen("http://rayatoys.com/traders/Георги-Куртев-02b15a41f8d1ec30a355ee17d404521c-1000-data", "r")) !== FALSE) {while (($data= fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) { $x_webnumber = $data[0]; //Номер на продукта необходим при заявки $x_systemnumber = $data[1]; //Системен номер на продукта необходим при заявки $x_category = $data[2]; //Категория$x_subcategory = $data[3]; //Подкатегория $x_tradeprice =$data[4]; //Минимална продажна Цена $x_weight = $data[5]; //Тегло на продукта $x_trademark = $data[6]; //Търговска марка - производител $x_sex = $data[7]; //M - момчета F - момичета MF - за всички $x_img = $data[8]; //Адрес на снимка - само по една снимка на продукт $x_name = $data[9]; //Наименование на продукта $x_text = $data[10]; //Описание на продукта //connect_to_your_db and make INSERT or UPDATE or whatever }fclose($handle); }
```

Comment: Now what should I do?

Comment: "Now what should I do?" is exactly the same thing I'm asking myself. I have no idea what exactly it is you are asking.